# What's the best postgresql index type to use for static, ordered data?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

In a postgreSQL database, I have an ~ 80 million row static data set that is rebuilt about once a year.  The data are physically ordered on the first two columns which are both integers, and queries will always use both of these fields (field1 = i and field2 between j and k).

I'm pretty sure 'multicolumn' would be good, and that 'cluster' wouldn't be too useful here, but beyond that is there a clear choice for a postgresql index type that can leverage the fact that rows are already in physical order and that the data are static.

Comment: Clustered indexes require that the data be in order.  It seems like the appropriate index, if you only want those two keys in it.

Comment: BRIN indexes come to mind. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/brin.html  but a regular BTree index would probably do just fine.But without the actual queries this is hard to answer. Remember: you index for _queries_, not for data